# To ping from one subnet to different subnet

Tags: embedded-linux

I have connected my laptop with both wifi and LAN with respected ip addresses 192.168.2.7(WiFi) and 192.168.1.7(LAN).

I connected the second laptop to the same LAN with ip address 192.168.1.10 (LAN).

Now i want to ping or to send message from my first laptop with ip address 192.168.2.7(WiFi) to second laptop with ip address 192.168.1.10 (LAN)

I tried many techniques which i found in different websites, but unable to get the result.

I also tried bridging method, but bridging method will work only under same "subnet".

The below are the different methods which i followed:

## Method 1:

vi /etc/sysctl.conf:
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1

sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf

service network restart

## Method 2:

brctl addbr mybridge

brctl addif mybridge eth0
brctl addif mybridge eth1

ifconfig mybridge up

ifconfig mybridge  netmask 255.255.255.0 up

Comment: You could add a static route on your router? Log in and create a static route from 192.168.2.7 to 192.168.1.10?

Answer (score 0):

Let me get this clear.

1. You have a *laptop1* that is connected to BOTH 1.x and 2.x
2. from *laptop1*, you want to ping *laptop2*, that is only connected to 1.x

In this case, since *laptop1* is directly connected to 1.x, it will use interface 1.7 to talk to anyone in network 1.x, and thus any packets sent will have the source address 1.7
If you force it to use src address 2.7 (why would you do that ? seems pointless to me) it won't work.

Unless you use some very deep iptables magic, your box will refuse to send a packet that originated from a local src address out over an interface that has a different src address.